# Problem with log filters in java (web3j). Maybe proble with geth parameters?

Tags: transactions, ethereumj, filters

I'm having trouble trying to create a simple contract that "just log" to the blockchain what is being sent from a java client. The transaction executing the log looks to be correct (how can I be sure about it?) but I find no way to retrieve the logs from the java client:

The smart-contract looks similar to:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract MyLogContract {
    event genericLog(
        uint256 indexed _index1, uint256 indexed _index2,  uint256 indexed _index3, string _log);

    function writeGenericLog01(
        uint256 _index1, uint256 _index2,  uint256 _index3,
        string _log) 
    returns (bool success) {
        genericLog(_index1, _index2, _index3, _log);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The java code looks similar to (userWrapper4Logs => use java wrapper, otherwise use hand-made transaction):

```
TransactionReceipt receipt;
if (!userWrapper4Logs){
     String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(
         new Function("writeGenericLog01", 
             Arrays.asList(Uint256.DEFAULT,
                 Uint256.DEFAULT, Uint256.DEFAULT, 
                 new Utf8String("Best log in Town!")) ,
              Arrays.asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {} )
          )
     );
     String from = ownerAddress;
     BigInteger gasPrice = BigInteger.valueOf(1),
                gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000L);
                nonce = null; // <- Ummm?
     String to = bc.listenerAPI_contractAddress;
     Transaction transaction = Transaction.
         createFunctionCallTransaction(
             from, nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, encodedFunction);

     Optional<TransactionReceipt> transactionResponse = 
          auxExecuteTransaction(transaction);

     receipt =  transactionResponse.get();
}
if (userWrapper4Logs) {
    MyLogContract wrapper = getContract(contractAddress, owner);
    receipt =  wrapper.writeGenericLog01(
             Uint256.DEFAULT, 
             Uint256.DEFAULT, 
             Uint256.DEFAULT, 
             new Utf8String("Best log in the wild wild West!")
         ).get();

}
System.out.println( ""
       + "\n BlockNumber()        : " + receipt.getBlockNumber()
       + "\n Cumulativ eGasUsed() : " + receipt.getCumulativeGasUsed()
       + "\n Log size             : " + receipt.getLogs().size() );
```

The transaction looks to execute properly and after mining 5 blocks the receipt is returned. Nothingness the *log size is always zero*. The STDOUT output looks similar to:

```
BlockNumber()        : 2528
Cumulativ eGasUsed() : 22872
Log size             : 0
```

I have some doubts about whether testrpc is able to handle log transactions or maybe they are just discarded by this sort of javascript node simulator, so I also tested with a real geth using next parameters (maybe something else is also needed):

$ geth --verbosity 4 --dev --maxpeers 0 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --networkid 1500 --mine --fakepow --minerthreads=1 --etherbase=0x......

(I also tried without the --dev option but then transaction looks to be never confirmed).

Thanks in advance for any help/hint or link!

**Update 201-05-09**: I tested the same contract with Truffle/web3js and logs are detected properly by the client, even using testrpc (only restricted to setup the event listener before submitting the transaction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a bug in the Filter.java class. The commit with the patch is available at:
https://github.com/earizon/web3j/commit/d0e641a4905f2900924df448d9b132d0bb34e4b0

I let a pull request on the main branch:
https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/115